# Wanted to increase ground clearance of Toyota Etios GD

Tags: toyota, tires, suspension

I am having Toyota Etios sedan GD SP. I wanted to increase Ground clearance of my car having with 14" wheels by using different size of tires. Plz suggest more. After doing some studies following points notice so sharing it's correct or not I don't know.

1. Keep the difference of 2% aspect ratio I can change the size of tire.
2. Giving an additional circular plate where the shock absorbers mounted on body.
3. Small circular spare which comes on Amazon which fits into the coil section.
   Sometimes I travel for few kms on poor roads as my job is of field work.

Please suggest me more.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Coilovers with adjustments would be your best bet. Upsizing tires will add an inch (unless you go beyond and make the ride unstable), bigger wheels will mean less tire compound and not comfy off road, any of those coil separators are risky (tempting and cheap). Get the Coilovers installed by a professional not just some regular local mechanic, you’ll need to import these from Thailand. Locally these are not produced.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please provide the name of importer from Thailand.

Comment: Where in India are you located?